# Populate (append) dict of dicts

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6, defaultdict

I am wanting to construct a dict of dicts.

I am extracting\processing output.  My output is exactly the way I want it:

Code snippet and resulting list from PyCharm

```
ssh_channel.send("show client detail 00:e0:4c:14:dd:78" + "\n")

time.sleep(0.9)
outp = ssh_channel.recv(100000)
shclisumstring = outp.decode("utf-8")
shclisumlist = shclisumstring.splitlines()

del shclisumlist[:1]
del shclisumlist[4:107]
del shclisumlist[6:]

shclisumlist[3] = shclisumlist[3].strip()
shclisumlist[4] = shclisumlist[4].strip()
shclisumlist[5] = shclisumlist[5].strip()
```

`<class 'list'>: ['Client MAC Address............................... 00:e0:4c:14:dd:78', 
                 'Client Username ................................. N/A', 
                 'AP MAC Address................................... 40:01:7a:80:44:40', 
                 'AP Name.......................................... AP1880.9025.f874', 
                 'Radio Signal Strength Indicator............ -53 dBm', 
                 'Signal to Noise Ratio...................... 47 dB']`

I will eventually iterate over all clients and each client will generate the same six lines of output. I am just doing one for now to get the logic straight.

At this point I want to populate a dict of dicts that will look like this:

`{'Client 1': {'Client MAC Address': '00:e0:4c:14:dd:78',
              'Client Username': 'N/A',
              'AP MAC Address': '40:01:7a:80:44:40',
              'AP Name': 'AP1880.9025.f874',
              'Radio Signal Strength Indicator': -53 dBm',
              'Signal to Noise Ratio': 47 dB'
              }`

The same pattern will repeat for Client 2, Client 3, etc.

Here is my code (partial):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)


while shclisumlist:
    ccounter = 1
    Client = 'Client ' + str(ccounter)
    for line in shclisumlist:
        regex = re.compile(r'(.+?)(?:\.+?\s)(.*)')
        mo = regex.search(line)
        d[Client] = ({mo.group(1): mo.group(2)})   <== Overwriting, not appending
```

The regex works, the dict populates with the first key:value pair, but the last line of my code is overwriting the inside dict instead of adding (appending?) to it.

Each iteration replaces the existing dict entry with the next one.  How do I get the inside dict to append?

This is the state after the fourth iteration:

`d = {defaultdict}defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Client 1': {'AP Name': 'AP1880.9025.f874'}})`

Answer (score 0):

Stepped away for a bit and came back to it.  This solves the issue:

`while shclisumlist:
    ccounter = 1
    Client = 'Client ' + str(ccounter)
    for line in shclisumlist:
        regex = re.compile(r'(.+?)(?:\.+?\s)(.*)')
        mo = regex.search(line)
        d[Client].update({mo.group(1): mo.group(2)})`